# Edit a record in json array with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to build a simple php aplication using json as data source.
So far I have retrieved, removed e added data from/to my json file , but I'm having trouble to update it.

My json file is like this:

```
{"categories":[
       {"id":"08a97ed88c141d179bf7710afe60bfe9","title":"TEST","thumb":".\/images\/test.jpg","desc":"adasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd","featured":true},
       {"id":"8f1bf832e9edb8564f517eb62d4f3b7c","title":"TEST 2","thumb":".\/images\/test 2.jpg","desc":"asdsdsdsadsadasdsdsadasdasdasdsadas","featured":true}
       ]}
```

I want to be able to update the value from one of the records key.

Here is how I try to update it:

```
$arr = file_get_contents('./data/categories.json');
$arr_obj = json_decode($arr, true);

foreach($arr_obj['categories'] as $key) {
  if($key['id'] == $_POST['catId']){
       $key['desc'] = $_POST['catDesc'];
  }
}
echo json_encode($arr_obj);
```

But no update is made in the json.

Any help will be apreciated!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you actually want to do:

```
<?php
//...
$arr = file_get_contents('./data/categories.json');
$arr_obj = json_decode($arr, true);

foreach($arr_obj['categories'] as $category) {
  if($category['id'] == $_POST['catId']){
       $arr_obj['categories'][$category]['desc'] = $_POST['catDesc'];
  }
}
echo json_encode($arr_obj);
```

The difference is that your own code set the description *on a copy* of an entry in that array, not on the original entry in the array.